# android several textview in layout and text wrap

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal LinearLayout containing 4 TextViews. Sometimes the text in one of these textviews is long, and the last textview does not fit correctly in the layout.
Of course, I can set one textview but this isn't optimal because the text is set from different places and has different styles.
Any idea how to solve this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weights to distribute the Views inside the LinearLayout with 25% each.

For example (untested, may contain typos):

```
<LinearLayout android:weightSum="100" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView android:layout_weight="25" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_weight="25" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_weight="25" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<TextView android:layout_weight="25" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```